# mariadb как создать таблицу

Tags: sql, mariadb

на сервере создал бд.

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - Ubuntu 18.04
PHP version: 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7

USE domains;
CREATE TABLE domains (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    domain text(50) NOT NULL,
    last_update timestamp DEFAULT FROM_UNIXTIME(1),
    mx_records json DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

код ошибки

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM_UNIXTIME(1),
    mx_records json DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id))' at line 4
```

в чём причина?

Comment: еще если поставлю вместо FROM_UNIXTIME(1) NULL выдает вот такую ошику #1067 - Invalid default value for 'last_update'

Comment: Если дефолтное значение является выражением, оно должно быть обёрнуто скобками.